# Clarification Needed Regarding $\sinh^{-1}(-3)$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

As the definition of $\sinh^{-1}(x)$  goes :

$\sinh^{-1}(x)=\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^{2}+1}\right)$

So what I expect to get is

$\sinh^{-1}(-3)=\ln\left(-3+\sqrt{10}\right)$

The value inside of the natural logarithm is positive because I can estimate that $\sqrt{10}$  is bigger than 3

However the answer in my textbook is $-\ln\left(3+\sqrt{10}\right)$

They claim that $\ln\left(-3+\sqrt{10}\right)=-\ln\left(3+\sqrt{10}\right)$

I know that $\ln(\frac{1}{x})=-\ln(x)$  But I am unable to make the connection with the answer in my textbook, is there any explanation for this ? is my first answer is correct ?

Comment: When working with numbers like $a + \sqrt{b}$, remember tricks like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sqrt{10}-3=\frac{(\sqrt{10}-3)(\sqrt{10}+3)}{\sqrt{10}+3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}+3}.
$$

Comment: and thus    $\ln\left(-3+\sqrt{10}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{3+\sqrt{10}}\right)=-\ln\left(3+\sqrt{10}\right)$  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$-3+\sqrt{10}=(-3+\sqrt{10})\cdot\frac{-3-\sqrt{10}}{-3-\sqrt{10}}=\frac{-1}{-3-\sqrt{10}}=(3+\sqrt{10})^{-1}$$